# C# A way to implement a GUI roster Datatable with duplicate Column names?

Tags: c#, duplicates, names

I am trying to create a rostering program and require several columns (28 in total), with each Day containing 4 columns (for instance |Monday| (On|Off|Duty|Hours) ).However I am running into some problems with duplicate column names I am also thinking weather it would be worth possibly splitting the tables into Days to alleviate this problem But feel this may affect future features (where I am comparing Cells day by days) Below is a picture of a completed table that I am attempting to replicate:

[image]

Do you think I am going about this the wrong way? or would it be possible to replicate this in a GUI ?

I am fairly new in the world of C# so apologies if this is something really simple!

Also apologies if this Question is slightly open to discussion.

Comment: Sorry i mean to say DataGRid not datatable!

Comment: What kind of problems? There is a difference between HeaderText and Column.Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you can see in column headers (HeaderText property) does not have to be the name of the column (Name property).

Thus a simple way to do what you want is to have Names be DayOfWeek_On/Off/Duty/Hours for example: Monday_On but have HeaderTExt be just On/Off/Duty/Hours.

Comment: Thank you, i completely Noobed out on this one! The other issue i am having is Having a Separate Header Above ON|OFF|DUTY|HOURS Is this possible? (referring to the table above ) of would this have to be done in a separate Finalised Output of the table?  if finalised i feel i would have issues with the initial Table edit form as it would be hard to read for someone who is inputting the data into the table (or hard to Auto format the cells sizes and have larger headers that still match up to the below 4 cells once data has been entered) Any ideas?

Comment: There is no off the shelf solution for stacked headers in Datagridview AFAIK. However this can be done very easily using Devexpress GridViews (not free).

Comment: For anyone Looking for a free way of doing Stacked Headers in DataGrid i would refer you too [DataGridView – Stacked Header- Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474418/DataGridViewplus-e-plusStackedplusHeader) for a very very nice example of how to do this (takes some understanding but really makes your programs GUI easily editable).